# Best way to convert JSON or other untyped data into typed classes in Swift?

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to parse out JSON into typed classes for safety/convenience, but it's proving very clunky. I wasn't able to find a library or even a post for Swift ([Jastor](https://github.com/elado/jastor) is as close as I got).  Here's a fabricated little snippet to illustrate:

```
// From NSJSONSerialization or similar and casted to an appropriate toplevel type (e.g. Dictionary). 
var parsedJson: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [ "int" : 1, "nested" : [ "bool" : true ] ]

class TypedObject {
    let stringValueWithDefault: String = ""
    let intValueRequired: Int
    let nestedBoolBroughtToTopLevel: Bool = false
    let combinedIntRequired: Int

    init(fromParsedJson json: NSDictionary) {
        if let parsedStringValue = json["string"] as? String {
            self.stringValueWithDefault = parsedStringValue
        }

        if let parsedIntValue = json["int"] as? Int {
            self.intValueRequired = parsedIntValue
        } else {
            // Raise an exception...?
        }

        // Optional-chaining is actually pretty nice for this; it keeps the blocks from nesting absurdly.
        if let parsedBool = json["nested"]?["bool"] as? Bool {
            self.nestedBoolBroughtToTopLevel = parsedBool
        }

        if let parsedFirstInt = json["firstInt"] as? Int {
            if let parsedSecondInt = json["secondInt"] as? Int {
                self.combinedIntRequired = parsedFirstInt * parsedSecondInt
            }
        }
        // Most succinct way to error if we weren't able to construct self.combinedIntRequired?
    }
}

TypedObject(fromParsedJson: parsedJson)
```

There's a number of issues here that I'm hoping to work around:

1. It's extremely verbose, since I need to wrap every single property in a copy-pasted `if`-`let` for safety.
2. I'm not sure how to communicate errors when required properties are missing (as noted above). Swift seems to prefer (?) using exceptions for show-stopping problems (rather than pedestrian malformed data as here).
3. I don't know a nice way to deal with properties that exist but are the wrong type (given that the `as?` casting will fail and simply skip the block, it's not very informative to the user).
4. If I want to translate a few properties into a single one, I need to nest the `let` blocks proportional to the number of properties I'm combining. (This is probably more generally a problem with combining multiple optionals into one value safely).

In general, I'm writing imperative parsing logic when I feel like I ought to be able to do something a little more declarative (either with some stated JSON schema or at least inferring the schema from the class definition).

Comment: I'm not sure I see any advantage to doing this at runtime. If you don't know at compile time what the types will be, you don't get any extra type protection. What do you see the benefit being?

Comment: The types are expected to be those as defined on the class. The point is to coerce the JSON into something that provides type safety as I shuttle it through my program and apply transformations to it, as well as catch any malformed input as early as possible. The only other option I see is to pass a `Dictionary` around, which is opaque and error-prone.

Comment: I think some pseudo-code of what your ideal situation is would help a lot

Comment: I'm assuming here you're referring to pseudocode for the conversion process (rather than the use of a converted, typed object). I come from Java so my ideal solution would be something along the lines of Jackson, which uses reflection to figure out mappings from JSON to Java objects, requiring relatively little work on the programmer's part ([here's a short example](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Full_Data_Binding_.28POJO.29_Example) if you're not familiar). Perhaps Swift isn't mature enough to do something comparable, but I was hoping for better than what I wrote above.

Comment: ya, that's not possible in swift yet

Comment: @stuffy See my answer below. There currently is no great way to do this in Swift. We can still use Obj-C to get around the issue for the pieces that need it and migrate them over to Swift once Apple addresses this missing feature.

Answer (score 0):

I do this using the [Jastor](https://github.com/elado/jastor) framework:

1) Implement a Protocol that has a single function that returns an `NSDictionary` response:

```
protocol APIProtocol {
    func didReceiveResponse(results: NSDictionary)
}
```

2) Create an API class that defines an `NSURLConnection` object that can be used as a Request URL for iOS's networking API. This class is created to simply return a payload from the `itunes.apple.com` API.

```
class API: NSObject {

    var data: NSMutableData = NSMutableData()
    var delegate: APIProtocol?

    func searchItunesFor(searchTerm: String) {

        // Clean up the search terms by replacing spaces with +
        var itunesSearchTerm = searchTerm.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "+",
            options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil)

        var escapedSearchTerm = itunesSearchTerm.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        var urlPath = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=\(escapedSearchTerm)&media=music"
        var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)
        var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        var connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)

        println("Search iTunes API at URL \(url)")

        connection.start()
    }

    // NSURLConnection Connection failed.
    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
        println("Failed with error:\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    // New request so we need to clear the data object.
    func connection(didReceiveResponse: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse!) {
        self.data = NSMutableData()
    }

    // Append incoming data.
    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!) {
        self.data.appendData(data)
    }

    // NSURLConnection delegate function.
    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {

        // Finished receiving data and convert it to a JSON object.
        var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data,
            options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary

        delegate?.didReceiveResponse(jsonResult)
    }

}
```

3) Create a class with associated properties that inherits from Jastor

**NSDictionary response:**

```
{
  "resultCount" : 50,
  "results" : [
    {
      "collectionExplicitness" : "notExplicit",
      "discCount" : 1,
      "artworkUrl60" : "http:\/\/a4.mzstatic.com\/us\/r30\/Features\/2a\/b7\/da\/dj.kkirmfzh.60x60-50.jpg",
      "collectionCensoredName" : "Changes in Latitudes, Changes in Attitudes (Ultmate Master Disk  Gold CD  Reissue)"
    }
   ]
}
```

**Music.swift**

```
class Music : Jastor {

    var resultCount: NSNumber = 0

}
```

4) Then in your ViewController be sure to set the delegate to self and then make a call to the API's `searchITunesFor()` method.

```
var api: API = API()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    api.delegate = self;
    api.searchItunesFor("Led Zeppelin")

}
```

5) Implement the Delegate method for `didReceiveResponse()`. Jastor extends your class to set a `NSDictionary` of the results returned from the iTunes API.

```
// #pragma - API Delegates

func didReceiveResponse(results: NSDictionary) {
    let music = Music(dictionary: results)
    println(music)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short version: Since init isn't allowed to fail, validation has to happen outside of it. Optionals seem to be the intended tool for flow control in these cases. My solution is to use a factory method that returns an optional of the class, and use option chaining inside it to extract and validate the fields.

Note also that `Int` and `Bool` aren't children of `AnyObject`; data coming from an `NSDictionary` will have them stored as `NSNumber`s, which can't be cast directly to Swift types. Thus the calls to `.integerValue` and `.boolValue`.

Long version:

```
// Start with NSDictionary since that's what NSJSONSerialization will give us
var invalidJson: NSDictionary = [ "int" : 1, "nested" : [ "bool" : true ] ]

var validJson: NSDictionary = [
    "int" : 1,
    "nested" : [ "bool" : true ],
    "firstInt" : 3,
    "secondInt" : 5
]


class TypedObject {

    let stringValueWithDefault: String = ""
    let intValueRequired: Int
    let nestedBoolBroughtToTopLevel: Bool = false
    let combinedIntRequired: Int

    init(intValue: Int, combinedInt: Int, stringValue: String?, nestedBool: Bool?) {

        self.intValueRequired = intValue
        self.combinedIntRequired = combinedInt

        // Use Optionals for the non-required parameters so
        // we know whether to leave the default values in place
        if let s = stringValue {
            self.stringValueWithDefault = s
        }

        if let n = nestedBool {
            self.nestedBoolBroughtToTopLevel = n
        }
    }

    class func createFromDictionary(json: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) -> TypedObject? {

        // Validate required fields
        var intValue: Int

        if let x = (json["int"]? as? NSNumber)?.integerValue {
            intValue = x
        } else {
            return nil
        }


        var combinedInt: Int

        let firstInt = (json["firstInt"]? as? NSNumber)?.integerValue
        let secondInt = (json["secondInt"]? as? NSNumber)?.integerValue

        switch (firstInt, secondInt) {
        case (.Some(let first), .Some(let second)):
            combinedInt = first * second
        default:
            return nil
        }

        // Extract optional fields
        // For some reason the compiler didn't like casting from AnyObject to String directly
        let stringValue = json["string"]? as? NSString as? String
        let nestedBool = (json["nested"]?["bool"]? as? NSNumber)?.boolValue

        return TypedObject(intValue: intValue, combinedInt: combinedInt, stringValue: stringValue, nestedBool: nestedBool)
    }

    class func createFromDictionary(json: NSDictionary) -> TypedObject? {
        // Manually doing this cast since it works, and the only thing Apple's docs
        // currently say about bridging Cocoa and Dictionaries is "Information forthcoming"
        return TypedObject.createFromDictionary(json as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
    }
}

TypedObject.createFromDictionary(invalidJson) // nil
TypedObject.createFromDictionary(validJson) // it works!
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also done the following to convert to/from:

```
class Image {
    var _id = String()
    var title = String()
    var subTitle = String()
    var imageId = String()

    func toDictionary(dict dictionary: NSDictionary) {
        self._id = dictionary["_id"] as String
        self.title = dictionary["title"] as String
        self.subTitle = dictionary["subTitle"] as String
        self.imageId = dictionary["imageId"] as String
    }

    func safeSet(d: NSMutableDictionary, k: String, v: String) {
        if (v != nil) {
            d[k] = v
        }
    }

    func toDictionary() -> NSDictionary {
        let jsonable = NSMutableDictionary()
        self.safeSet(jsonable, k: "title", v: self.title);
        self.safeSet(jsonable, k: "subTitle", v: self.subTitle);
        self.safeSet(jsonable, k: "imageId", v: self.imageId);

        return jsonable
    }
}
```

Then I simply do the following:

```
// data (from service)
let responseArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSArray

self.objects = NSMutableArray()
for item: AnyObject in responseArray {
    var image = Image()
    image.toDictionary(dict: item as NSDictionary)
    self.objects.addObject(image)
}
```

If you want to POST the data:

```
var image = Image()
image.title = "title"
image.subTitle = "subTitle"
image.imageId = "imageId"

let data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(image.toDictionary(), options: .PrettyPrinted, error: nil) as NSData

// data (to service)
request.HTTPBody = data;
```